# Django get field rendering as string

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I get a field rendering from html after form init?

I am trying to add some custom html to the form like this:

```
class BaseForm(Form):
    render_report = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        html_rendering = str(self.fields['render_report'])
```

The conflicting part is `str(self.fields['render_report'])`. How can I obtain the html rendering of render_report?. Of course, str() doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some headbanging, here is the catch:
The rendered fields are accesed via the form's _ _ getitem _ _().

So I had to change `self.fields['render_report']` for `self['render_report']`